# Drupal: CCK ImageField, multi-line description

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using CCK Image field (multi-images) and for each image I have the "Description" field, where I can add the image description.

I was wondering if I can have multi-line description, instead of only one line.

(Even using some specific symbol to go next line)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting a textarea instead of a textfield for the image description field, the only way to do this would be to create a custom module that creates a compound field. There is a really great tutorial on the state of compound fields in Drupal and how to create one here: http://poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module.

Alternatively, if you only have one image you are uploading, you could disable the description on the image field and create an additional CCK textarea to be used as the description.

Answer (score 0):

When you create CCK imagefield, there is a setting called "Title text settings", where you can set the checkbox "Enable custom title text" and select Input type: textarea instead of textfield.

So now there is nothing you must to specially to make a multiply description for your every imagefield.